# Round up floats to first decimal point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a number to be rounded up to first decimal position

```
>>> round(1.2345, 2)
1.3
>>> round(1.261, 2)
1.3
```

I know one solution so far

```
>>> math.ceil(1.2345 * 10) / 10
1.3
```

Is there another way?

Comment: you should mention that `round(1.2345, 2)` returns `1.23` and `round(1.261, 2)` returns `1.26` in Python. Perhaps, you meant you want a new function `round_up(1.2345, 1)` that would produce `1.3` (close).

Comment: I know, what I want actually is 1.30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `decimal.ROUND_UP` and [`.quantize()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize)to round a decimal to a fixed number of places:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP
>>> Decimal(1.2345).quantize(Decimal(".1"), rounding=ROUND_UP)
Decimal('1.3')
```

You can play around with the first parameter (*precision*) to specify the number of digits you want:

```
>>> Decimal(1.2375).quantize(Decimal(".001"), rounding=ROUND_UP)
Decimal('1.238')
```

Comment: How if I want the number to be filled with one extra zero like 1.30?

Comment: 1.3 and 1.30 are equal. You can't create a floating value with a zero at the end because it is not necessary. I think you are trying to format a floating value. How about: `print('%.2f' % 1.3)`

Comment: @TomNg: if you want to add extra zero to  a `Decimal`, to communicate the precision: `Decimal('1.3') * Decimal('1.0')`